# Problems with wireless driver for Edimax EW-7711ULC adapter

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I'm trying to make the Edimax EW-7711ULC usb adapter work with Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64 bit.

I first tried using the official driver, which didn't work and the system didn't pick up the adapter at all.

I've tried following the instructions here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/509498/is-there-a-standard-wifi-driver-for-the-edimax-ew-7811un

and here

https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000035492-how-to-resolve-ew-7811un-built-in-driver-issues-in-linux-kernel-v3-10-or-higher

Now the adapter is recognised, the light turns on as soon as I plug it in. However the system freezes instantly at this point.

Rebooting causes it to hang on a black screen.

Unplugging the adapter and rebooting makes everything work as normal.

How can I identify the problem and get this adapter working?

Comment: Please detail what you have done to debug the situation until now, with logs, in text mode.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure how to proceed with debugging